# How to determine if image captured using UIImagePickerController is JPEG or HEIF?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11, heif

I have set the imageExportPreset property of the UIImagePickerController to use current. How can I determine if the image captured is HEIF or JPEG?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like the following?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    NSURL *assetURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    NSString *extension = [assetURL pathExtension];
    CFStringRef imageUTI = (UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)extension , NULL));

    if (UTTypeConformsTo(imageUTI, kUTTypeJPEG))
    {
        // JPEG
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled Image UTI: %@", imageUTI);
    }
}
```

Comment: assetURL is nil (and therefore imageUTI is nil).